# Exact change java

Tags: java

I don't know how I would go about getting an output that goes through the math but won't return a 0 in some cases. For instance, 45, I do not want the output from nickels and pennies being 0 after the quarters and dimes output

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int totalChange = scnr.nextInt();
      int pennies;
      int nickels;
      int dimes;
      int quarters;
      int dollars;
  
      if(totalChange == 0)
      {
          System.out.println("No Change");
          System.exit(0);
      }
      dollars = totalChange / 100;
      totalChange %= 100;
      System.out.println(dollars + " Dollar");
      quarters = totalChange / 25;
      totalChange %= 25;
      System.out.println(quarters + " Quarter");
      dimes = totalChange / 10;
      totalChange %= 10;
      System.out.println(dimes + " Dimes");
      nickels = totalChange / 5;
      totalChange %= 5;
      System.out.println(nickels + " Nickles");
      pennies = totalChange / 1;
      totalChange %= 1;
      System.out.println(pennies + " Pennies");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: same way you avoid printing the change when no change is needed.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried putting the dollar through an if statement in order to get it to not print when I didn't need it like with 45, but I ended up just messing the whole thing up

Comment: Actually these hints helped me figure it out!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user16320675 Sometimes it may be preferrable to stick to a pattern, though; especially if the compiler optimizes the extra code away. Maybe the user may want to convert this to a more universal solution working with a table of coin names and values...

Answer (score 2):

Just put an if condition before every print statement as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int totalChange = scnr.nextInt();
      int pennies;
      int nickels;
      int dimes;
      int quarters;
      int dollars;
  
      if(totalChange == 0)
      {
          System.out.println("No Change");
          System.exit(0);
      }
      dollars = totalChange / 100;
      totalChange %= 100;
      if(dollars!=0){
          System.out.println(dollars + " Dollar");
      }
      quarters = totalChange / 25;
      totalChange %= 25;
      if(quarters!=0){
          System.out.println(quarters + " Quarter");
      }
      dimes = totalChange / 10;
      totalChange %= 10;
      if(dimes!=0){
          System.out.println(dimes + " Dimes");
      }
      nickels = totalChange / 5;
      totalChange %= 5;
      if(nickels!=0){
          System.out.println(nickels + " Nickles");
      }
      pennies = totalChange / 1;
      totalChange %= 1;
      if(pennies!=0){
          System.out.println(pennies + " Pennies");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts here. First, once the `totalChange` hits `0`, you don't need to keep calculating. Second, you may not need some coins (e.g., if the change is 4 cents, you probably don't want to print 0 dollar, 0 quarters, etc. You can check these cases explicitly.

Let's show an example with the quarters case:

```java
if (totalChange == 0) {
     // We're done!
     System.exit(0);
}

// If there still is change, we need to calculate it:
quarters = totalChange / 25;
totalChange %= 25;

// But this change may not require quarters:
if (quarters > 0) {
    System.out.println(quarters + " Quarter");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this and it worked great!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int totalChange = scnr.nextInt();
      int pennies;
      int nickels;
      int dimes;
      int quarters;
      int dollars;
  
      if(totalChange == 0)
      {
          System.out.println("No change");
          System.exit(0);
      }
  
  
      dollars = totalChange / 100;
      totalChange %= 100;
      if(dollars > 0)
      {
          if(dollars >= 2)
      {
          System.out.println(dollars + " Dollars");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println(dollars + " Dollar");
      }
  }
  
  quarters = totalChange / 25;
  totalChange %= 25;
  if(quarters > 0)
  {
      if(quarters >= 2)
      {
          System.out.println(quarters + " Quarters");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(quarters + " Quarter");
      }
  }
  dimes = totalChange / 10;
  totalChange %= 10;
  if(dimes > 0)
  {
      if(dimes >= 2)
      {
          System.out.println(dimes + " Dimes");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println(dimes + " Dime");
      }
  }
  nickels = totalChange / 5;
  totalChange %= 5;
  if(nickels > 0)
  {
           if(nickels >= 2)
           {
               System.out.println(nickels + " Nickels");
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println(nickels + " Nickel");
           }
      }
      pennies = totalChange / 1;
       totalChange %= 1;
       if(pennies > 0)
       {
          if(pennies >= 2)
          {
              System.out.println(pennies + " Pennies");
          }
           else
          {
              System.out.println(pennies + " Penny");
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: As the plural is just appending `s`, have you considered writing a function receiving a number and a string, returning the correct unit string depending on the number? Or that function could print both, the number and the correct unit. It's called "procedural abstraction". It will make your code shorter and more regular.